# While Exporting from crystal viewer in chrome, file extensions are changed

Tags: google-chrome, crystal-reports, export

While I am trying to export an XLS from a crystal report viewer (using c#), 
I get the following file name
**"CrystalReportViewer1.xls X-XSS-Protection- 0.xls X-XSS-Protection- 0"**
where i expect only **"CrystalReportViewer1.xls"**
This is happening only in Chrome, and working good in IE.
is it some thing to do with Chrome settings? or something to do in C# ?

Thanks in advance.